# How to redirect a user to a page that is set in a Session?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, asp-classic

I need to redirect a user and i am using this JS code

```
response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You do not have permissions to access this page.""); location.href = 'Session("CurrentPage")' </SCRIPT>")
```

I am setting the session on each page i visit and in theory this should redirect to the page i was last on, any advice on how i would get this to work?

Comment: In server side , whih language you are using ? php?

Comment: I'm using ASP @Birlla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is server side, so you need to do it like this:

```
response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">alert(""You do not have permissions to access this page.""); location.href = '" & Session("CurrentPage") & "' </SCRIPT>")
```